# Doxygen generated latex failing with pdflatex

Tags: doxygen, pdflatex

I have generated latex with doxygen, then I run the `make pdf` command.

This is the first time I tried it.

```
[mysite.lan] (liberz) latex> make pdf
rm -f *.ps *.dvi *.aux *.toc *.idx *.ind *.ilg *.log *.out *.brf *.blg *.bbl refman.pdf
pdflatex refman
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013)
 restricted \write18 enabled.

kpathsea: Running mktexfmt pdflatex.fmt
/usr/bin/mktexfmt: line 395: /usr/share/texlive/texmf/texconfig/tcfmgr: No such file or directory
fmtutil: config file `fmtutil.cnf' not found.
I can't find the format file `pdflatex.fmt'!
make: *** [refman.pdf] Error 1
```

I looked at the `mkexfmt` command and it is trying to invoke `tcfmgr` as a command.

The `/usr/share/texlive/texmf/texconfig` folder exists, but there is no `tcfmgr` command in it.

Previously I was getting the `pdflatex` command was not found, so that is recently installed.

[edit to answer version information question] I am sure I need to install more tools, but it is not clear what packages I need to install.  I am using CentOS 7.1.

```
> pdflatex -version
pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013)
kpathsea version 6.1.1
Copyright 2013 Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
Compiled with libpng 1.5.13; using libpng 1.5.13
Compiled with zlib 1.2.7; using zlib 1.2.7
Compiled with poppler version 0.22.5
```

Comment: Which latex distribution have you installed? Maybe you should ensure that you have all necessary tools installed. This includes a latex distribution (like MikTex), a TCL interpreter (like ActiveTCL) and Ghostscript.

Comment: In command line type `doxygen -w latex headerFile footerFile styleSheetFile` to let doxygen create a latex header file and stylesheet file. Then you can analyze those files to find out which latex packages are used by the latex code created by doxygen.

Comment: For future reference: This error `I can't find the format file pdflatex.fmt` means that the TeX distribution is broken, and it is best to reinstall. It should never happen (but clearly it can).

Answer (score 2):

Doxygen PDF output depends on `pdflatex` command, which in CentOS 7 is provided by `texlive-latex-bin-bin` package, but runnig `make pdf` invokes yet another command, `tcfmgr`, which is provided by `texlive-texconfig`, hence, run the following command to install those dependencies:

```
yum install -y texlive-latex-bin-bin texlive-texconfig
```

You can check which packages provide any necessary file:

```
$ yum --quiet provides "*bin/pdflatex"

...
2:texlive-latex-bin-bin-svn14050.0-38.20130427_r30134.el7.noarch :
Binaries for latex-bin
Repo        : base
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/pdflatex

$ yum --quiet provides /usr/share/texlive/texmf/texconfig/tcfmgr

...
2:texlive-texconfig-svn29349.0-38.el7.noarch : texconfig package
Repo        : base
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/share/texlive/texmf/texconfig/tcfmgr
```

But even with these 2 basic requirements satisfied, I found that many other messages followed, and the whole list to reduce warnings was:

```
xargs <<_EOF_ yum -y install
texlive-latex-bin-bin
texlive-texconfig
texlive-metafont-bin
texlive-iftex
texlive-cm
texlive-xtab
texlive-multirow
texlive-ec
texlive-sectsty
texlive-fancyhdr
texlive-natbib
texlive-tocloft
texlive-tex4ht
texlive-helvetic
texlive-pslatex
texlive-courier
texlive-times
texlive-metapost
texlive-symbol
texlive-rsfs
texlive-dvips
texlive-base
texlive-makeindex-bin
_EOF_

...
Transaction Summary
==============================================================================================================================
Install  23 Packages (+132 Dependent packages)

Total download size: 43 M
Installed size: 134 M
...
```

And yet Tex2PDF conversion produces many warnings, but the resulting document is quite satisfatory.

[Edited on Nov 8th]
If you want a *"recommended"* package installation, you might choose one of these *"virtual"* packages that require other sets of packages, to compose a more *"complete"* Latex environment, in order of higher comprehensiveness:

- `texlive-collection-latex` : LaTeX fundamental packages
- `texlive-collection-latexrecommended` : LaTeX recommended packages
- `texlive`

Comment: @MichaelPotter, please let me know if my question were of any help for your CentOS question, or any other doubt about it.